# How to render large rich text into ag-grid cell?

Tags: ag-grid, richtextbox

I am trying to display large (up to 25k characters) rich text in the ag-grid cell. I want to display only specific text at first with show more link. When you click on show more link whole text will be shown with show less link.
Rich text includes bold, italic, underline, text-color, bullets, numbering, image, etc.

This leads to dynamic height change for cells. I need to calculate the height for each cell depending on the text.

Do anyone have any idea, how the dynamic height can be handled? Or Is there any npm library to handle such kind of requirement?

I am using ag-grid with angukar9 am using ag-grid version 23 with angular9, so autoHeight feature is not available.

So basically, I have requirement for rendering larger rich text into ag-grid cell with dynamic height, do anyone have any approach for this thing. Please let me know.

[show_more](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBX1s.png)
[show_less](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1NtE.png)

Comment: Although, I came here searching for something similar, our use case isnt for 25k characters. Did you find your answer?

Comment: Hi Guys, Any luck with this one ? I have a similar requirement and not able to find any proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

this is worked for me try it   {
headerName: 'الوصف',
field: 'description',
minWidth: 300,
colId: 'col1',
cellRenderer: (params) => {
return `<p class="sub-title"  style=" max-height: 100%; display: -webkit-box; -webkit-box-orient: vertical; -webkit-line-clamp: 3; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: break-spaces; direction: rtl ">${params.value} </p>`
},